Red Hat OpenShift Local installation on Windows 11 fails with message "requires the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709) or newer"
I'm being unable to install latest OpenShift Local in Windows 11 laptop.
I've administrator privileges in the machine.
Installer shows error:
"Red Hat OpenShift Local requires the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709) or newer."
Downloaded the latest OpenShift Local (it seems to be 2.33) from:
https://console.redhat.com/openshift/create/local
but I can't install it in my laptop which meets all requirements (windows version, memory, vCPUs and free space on C:).
The laptop has:
Windows 11 version 23H2, with all available updates applied
I've administrator privileges in the machine.
Right after starting the .msi install, a pop-up windows is shown with message:
"Red Hat OpenShift Local requires the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709) or newer."
Any idea on how install OpenShift Local on Windows 11?

OpenShift Local 2.34 has been released, but still unable to install it.
Laptop: Fully updated Windows 11 Pro Version 23H2 (OS Build 22631.3447)
crc-windows-amd64.msi aborts install with message "Red Hat OpenShift Local requires the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709) or newer."

will you please let me know if your installation went through successfully? do you need some kind of license to run OpenShift Local?

We didn't succeed at all with the installation. Finally, we decided to use OKD instead.

I had the same problem, I tried to install from cmd as admin and it worked.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
